# React: How to display a index of an array which is an object containing an image

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have a collection of images I am using to populate a Carousel component which I'm trying to create:

```
const images = [{img: 'url'},{img: 'url'},{img: 'url'}];
```

What i'd like is way to create a handler for a button, (next and prev) which could jump to the halfway point and then the beginning and repeat.

Previously I did something like this:

```
   const handleNext = () => {

    let newg = [...gallery];

    if (activeIdx == gallery.length - 1) {
      setActiveIdx(val => val = -1)
    }
 
    if (activeIdx != gallery.length / 2) {
      setActiveIdx(val => val + nextBatch)
      setIsNext(isNext => !isNext);

      let splice = newg.splice(nextBatch - 1);
      setGallery(() => [...splice, ...newg]);

    } else {
      setActiveIdx(0)
    }
  }
```

I soon realized this does emulate the affect of going to a point in the array, but because it's generating a new array and adding it to the DOM, applying an animation to the action, like easing for example has no effect. Because it's not moving to a part in the array; the starting point in the div/view becomes the  new starting point in the array after the splice.

Part in question:

```
   let splice = newg.splice(nextBatch - 1);
   setGallery(() => [...splice, ...newg]);
```

This is it in [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-gagarin-41mdg).

This is my whole component:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef } from 'react';
import cx from 'classnames';

const images = [{img: 'url'},{img: 'url'},{img: 'url'}];

const Carousel = () => {
  const [items, setItems] = useState(() => Array.from(Array(images.length).keys()));
  const [gallery, setGallery] = useState(images);

  const [nextBatch, setNextBatch] = useState(null);
  const [amountOfDots, setAmountOfDots] = useState(1);
  const [isNext, setIsNext] = useState(true)

  const [activeIdx, setActiveIdx] = useState(0);
    
  const handleNext = () => {

    console.log("items ", items);
    if (activeIdx == gallery.length - 1) {
      setActiveIdx(val => val = -1)
    }
    if (activeIdx != gallery.length / 2) {
      setActiveIdx(val => val + nextBatch)
      setIsNext(isNext => !isNext)
    } else {
      setActiveIdx(0)
    }
  }

  const createItem = (idx) => {
    const item = {
      image: gallery[idx].image,
      title: gallery[idx].title
    };
    return item;
  };

  const CarouselSlideItem = ({ idx }) => {
    const item = createItem(idx);
    return (
      <>
        <div className={styles.frame} style={item.styles}>
          <img src={item.image} alt={item.title} />
        </div>
        <div className={styles.carouselSlideItem__body}>
          <p> {item.title}</p>
        </div >
      </>
    );
  };

  useEffect(() => {

    var arrayLength = items.length;

    if (arrayLength % 2 === 0) {
      setAmountOfDots(2)
      setNextBatch(items[arrayLength / 2])
    }
  }, [activeIdx]);


  return (

    <div className={styles.wrapper}>

      <div ref={nodeRef} className={styles.carousel}

        style={isGalleryWidthInline ? {
          maxWidth: '465px'
        } : null}
      >
        <div className={styles.carousel__inner} >
          {

            items.map((pos, i) => (
              <CarouselSlideItem
                key={i}
                idx={i}
              />
            ))
          }

        </div>
        <button onClick={() => console.log('bar')} className={cx(styles.nav, styles.prev)}><i className={`fas fa-chevron-left fa-2x ${styles.icon}`}></i></button>
        <button onClick={() => handleNext()} className={cx(styles.nav, styles.next)}><i className={`fas fa-chevron-right fa-2x ${styles.icon}`}></i></button>
      </div>
      <ul className={styles[`carousel__dots`]}>

        {Array.from(Array(amountOfDots).keys()).map((dot) => {
          return (
            <li className={styles.dot} onClick={() => { console.log('foo') }} />
          )
        })}
      </ul>
    </div>
      );
};

export default Carousel;
```

So how would you create a handler which would jump to part of an array?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's only here but I can't run your codesandbox snippet. It keeps "Installing Dependencies 1/18 (web-vitals)"

Comment: @testing_22 Thanks for checking in...I checked it on my phone and a few browsers on my macbook and it works...